# Is it possible to use the standard Music application to select an audio file?

Tags: android, audio, dialog, id3-tag

in my application, I want to be able to select an audio file which is on the device to be used. The standard audio player in Android 2.3 "Music" offers everything I need to fullfill the requirements. Is it possible to send an Intent to open the Music app, select a song and give back the audio file id as result to my application?

thanks in advance!

greets,
Andi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the [`INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_SEARCH`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_SEARCH)? It seems to do what you are looking for..

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. Actually, instead of playing the file on selection, I  would like to retrieve the MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA information and store it somewhere for later use. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: what does the above intent do? play the song? If it does then you might have to query the database and get a list of songs and present the songs to the  user in a list by yourself..

Comment: Exactly. It offers a list with all Audio files and playes the selected one. I guess I have to query the database and build an own selection dialog. But thanks anyway!